# Can anyone tell me this MD Bootstrap Snippet doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, navigation

https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/mdbootstrap/98655

Zoom out to 25% or so, maybe farther, but you will see, the toolbar pops open, and won't close. How can I avoid this? Asked this yesterday and all I got was downvotes :(

Thanks for any effort given

Comment: do you think you'll get a better response today?

Comment: If you go to https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/admin-dashboard-lesson-3/ you'll see it happen there too - it's the design

Comment: Are you referring to the "sidenav"? if so `$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
breakpoint: 10000
});` will make it so it's hidden unless your screen width is 10000 pixels :p

Comment: Zooming out to 25% means the screen is gaining more space for the content. So the toolbar is not needed to be collapsed in that case. Think like that.

Comment: @Bravo that seemed like a good idea but no luck :( Thanks anyway

Comment: really? worked for me - you are talking about the sidenav correct?

Answer (score 0):

Some script is adding inline styles to the toolbar. The script might be listening to `resize` event.

(hidden toolbar)

```
<div id="slide-out" class="side-nav sn-bg-4 fixed" style="transform: translateX(-100%);">
```

vs 
(show toolbar)

```
<div id="slide-out" class="side-nav sn-bg-4 fixed" style="transform: translateX(0%);">
```